# Ошибка до загрузки формы

Tags: c#, .net, mvp, inversion-of-control, unity-container

При загрузке формы возникает ошибка вида

```
System.StackOverflowException HResult=0x800703E9 Сообщение = Выдано исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException".
```

и выполнение кода приостанавливается. В Program.cs я задаю такие параметры

```
UnityClogin =
                new UnityContainer()
                .RegisterType<ILoginView, LoginView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                .RegisterType<ILoginPresenter, LoginPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                .RegisterType<IAuthorizationUser, AuthorizationUser>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                .RegisterType<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

ILoginPresenter loginPresenter = UnityClogin.Resolve<LoginPresenter>();
ILoginView loginView = loginPresenter.GetLoginView();

Application.Run((LoginView)loginView);
```

В форме

```
public partial class LoginView : Form, ILoginView
    {
        ILoginPresenter _loginPresenter;
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

        public LoginView(ILoginPresenter loginPresenter)
        {
            _loginPresenter = loginPresenter;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Падает здесь

```
ILoginPresenter loginPresenter = UnityClogin.Resolve<LoginPresenter>();
```

Код LoginPresenter

```
public loginpresenter(iloginview loginview,
                              iauthorizationservice authorizationservice)
        {
            _authorizationservice = authorizationservice;
            _loginview = loginview;
            subscribetoeventssetup();
        }

        public ILoginView GetLoginView() => _loginView;

        private void SubscribeToEventsSetup()
        { }

        public void OnAuthorizeUser(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            If (_authorizationService.AuthorizeUser(UserName, Password))
                _loginView.IsAuthenticated = true;

            _loginView.CheckAuthorizationUser(_loginView.IsAuthenticated);
        }
```

Comment: а у вас случайно `LoginPresenter` не использует в конструкторе `LoginView`?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я обращаюсь к интерфейсу ILoginView loginView, это разве из за этого? Мне от туда необходимо вызывать методы LoginView и из него же обращаться к Presenter

Comment: То есть у вас есть класс А, который в конструктор хочет класс Б, который в конструктор хочет класс А, который в конструктор хочет класс Б и так далее, верно?

Comment: @tym32167 я вас понял) подскажите пожалуйста, а как тогда лучше обратиться к классу Presenter и так же обращаться обратно?

Comment: так вы кода не показали, для чего вам презентер и вью? Как вы их используете внутри каждого класса? Почему они должны знать друг о друге?

Comment: @tym32167 код LoginPresenter закинул в топик, они должны знать что бы из LoginPresenter я мог обратиться к метода в LoginView после выполнения авторизации и там уже отработать остальные манипуляции. А из LoginView я вызову OnAuthorizeUser, что бы проверить авторизацию

Comment: в таких случаях обычно 2 варианта: 1) вводить 3 объект, например, шину сообщений между компонентами - она ни от кого не зависит, а компоненты могут на неё подписаться, чтобы получать события 2) - создавать сущности с циклическими зависимостями руками (или собственноручно написанными фабриками) и уже созданные объекты (или фабрики) регистрировать в контейнере. Сам контейнер без помощи не сможет резолвить циклические зависимости графов объектов

Comment: tym32167 но это наверное не верно с точки зрения архитектуры, в MVP вью не должна знать о Presenter… Но мне нужно обратиться к нему с данными. Раньше я вводил свойства у формы и через них получал информацию, но это тоже не есть хорошо. Для решения такой проблемы тоже лучше вводить 3 объект?

Comment: Может, для передачи информации от вью к презентеру имеет смысл использовать события? https://habr.com/post/211899/ А для чего вам MVP? У вас WinForms?

Comment: @tym32167 да, я использую WinForm. Я раньше использовал события, и сначала я передаю username событию, потом его же беру в Presenter, назначаю при передаче обратно, разве так верно? Просто потом у меня появляется около 20 значений которые по мере необходимости надо будет записывать в события, для упорядочивания я могу их записать в модели, но все равно я думал так не правильно

Comment: В моем понимании событие - это однонаправленная передача данных, то есть если View хочет что то отправить презентеру, она не долна знать о презентере, она просто создает событие, а так как презентер на него подписан, он получает это событие. Но чтобы что то отправить от презентера во вью, презентер должен вызвать метод\свойство этого вью Не используйте события представления для передачи данных от презентера, от этого только сами себе сделаете хуже - запутаетесь потом в коде.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое за помощь и разъяснение, так и поступлю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, удачи с приложением :)